# Ionic5 provider with local storage and remote sync

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am thinking to implement a data provider that would store a copy of backend data locally for it to be available readily. Guess this would be called mirroring or so.

However, it needs to be synced / updated to remain consistent with the backend.

I'm thinking of a provider with a data model copy such as either local storage for persistence or a singleton object if it's only for mirroring during runtime.

What are exiting solutions in the ionic / angular library for this?
Please note, we have a custom backend, no firebase or similar solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic and Angular do not provide standard functionality for this. It is outside the scope of these frameworks.

You could create a service that caches the data and periodically goes to the server to refresh the data. You can also do it more generally with an *interceptor*. The Angular guide has [an example](https://angular.io/guide/http#using-interceptors-for-caching).

You could also use a *service worker* to achieve this. Angular has [some support for this](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro).

If you do not change the data locally (in the app) and data is only changed remotely (on the server) this is relatively straightforward. If you change data on both sides, this can be difficult to implement, because you can get synchronization conflicts.

If you have a lot of data, and it needs to be persistent, it is probably better to use IndexedDB for storage.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to store the data locally on the device using Sqlite

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite

You can define a data model that you can then synchronize with your backend, validating the availability of the network, for this you can use

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network

I hope it helps you to start your solution